# Maps with jacobian determinant equal to +1 or -1

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I've been working on finding bijective functions $g: [0,1]^2 \mapsto D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $g(U_1, U_2)$ has a given probability density $d$, where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are uniform random variables of $[0,1]$. Using probability integral transformation, I have found such a function, but I would now like to find other ones that fulfill other conditions (namely being a gradient field).

I have found that all other solutions of my problem can be written $g\circ f$ where $f:[0, 1]^2 \mapsto [0, 1]^2$ is a bijective function such that $\left|\textrm{det}\left(Jac(f)(x)\right)\right| = 1$ for all $x\in[0, 1]^2$.

Are there other characterizations of such functions? How would one go about building them?

Comment: The title of your question seems to want a Jacobian to be _orthogonal_, whereas the actual text only seems to speak about it having determinant $1$. How do those fit together?

Comment: You are right, I made a false equivalence (Not all matrices of determinant +-1 are orthogonal…). What is important is for the map to preserve area so as not to change the probability density. I’ve edited the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get a volume-preserving map is to integrate a (time-dependent) divergence-free vector field (i.e. to compute $f(x)$ solve the ODE $v'(t)=X_t(v(t))$ for IVP $v(0)=x$ and put $f(x)=v(1)$). You will need to make sure that the solutions stay in the domain, by making $X_t$ behave appropriately near the boundary.

"Moser's trick" says that all volume-preserving diffeos isotopic to identity are obtained this way.

For a disk in dimension 2, this means that all of them are obtained this way (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9335/why-is-every-symplectomorphism-of-the-unit-disk-hamiltonian-isotopic-to-the-iden; in dimension 2 "Hamiltonian" and "divergence- free" are the same thing). I believe the fact that you want it on $[0,1]^2$ should not change the conclusion, but I have not checked the details, and you may need to specify boundary conditions more precisely to get a specific result of this type.